# Test Method is failing

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

Controller :

```
  public class WizardClass   
  {  
      public Opportunity Oppo{get;set;}  
      public List<Quote> quoteList{get;set;}    

    public WizardClass()
    {
        Oppo = new Opportunity();
        quoteList = new List<Quote>();
        quoteList.add(new quote());
    }

    public void CreateQuote()
    {
        quoteList.add(new quote());
        }

    **public PageReference QuotePage()
    {
        return Page.OppoQuotes;
        }**

    public PageReference Create()
    {
        insert Oppo;   
        **List<Quote> quoList = new List<Quote>();
        for(Quote q : quoteList)
        {
            Quote quo = new Quote();
            quo.OpportunityId = Oppo.id;
            quo.name = q.name;
            quoList.add(quo);
            }
       // q.OpportunityId = Oppo.id;
        insert quoList;
        PageReference newPage = new PageReference('/'+Oppo.id);
        return newPage;
        }**


  }
```

Test Class :

```
  @isTest  
  Private class WizardClassTest  
  {  
    static testMethod void unitTest()   
    {    
        Test.starttest() ;  
        Opportunity opp = new opportunity();  
        opp.Name = 'Roy';  
        opp.closeDate = system.today();  
        opp.stageName = 'Prospecting' ;  
        Insert opp;  
        List<Quote> quoteList = new List<Quote>();  
        Quote q = new Quote();  
        q.name = 'Joe';  
        q.opportunityId = opp.Id;  
        quoteList.add(q);  
        Quote quo = new Quote();  
        quo.name = 'Monroe';  
        quo.opportunityId = opp.Id;  
        quoteList.add(quo);  
        insert quoteList;  
        System.assertEquals(2,opp.quotes.size());  
        Test.stoptest();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should query on quotes before `System.assertEquals(2,opp.quotes.size());`

Comment: query how? can yo plz tell me...

Answer (score 1):

I think is because you dont cover the method. Try add this

```
@isTest  
Private class WizardClassTest  
{      
static testMethod void unitTest()   
{    
    Test.starttest() ;  
    Account acc = new Account(Name='test acc');
    insert acc;
    Opportunity opp = new opportunity();  
    opp.Name = 'Roy';
    opp.AccountId = acc.id;  
    opp.closeDate = system.today();  
    opp.stageName = 'Prospecting' ;  
    Insert opp;  

    List<Quote> quoteList = new List<Quote>();  
    Quote q = new Quote();  
    q.name = 'Joe';  
    q.opportunityId = opp.Id;  
    quoteList.add(q);  
    Quote quo = new Quote();  
    quo.name = 'Monroe';  
    quo.opportunityId = opp.Id;  
    quoteList.add(quo);  
    insert quoteList;  

    WizardClass wc = new WizardClass();
    quoteList = wc.quoteList;
    System.assertEquals(2,quoteList.size());
    wc.CreateQuote();
    wc.Create();
    wc.QuotePage();  
    Test.stoptest();  
    }  
}
```

can you please attach which line its not covered by your code. it will make us easier to help you

Comment: the code coverage has gone to 45% only...can you suggest me something else.

Comment: try run the test on developer console because you can see the lines of code are covered. `Test->New Run->Pick your Test Class->Run->Open your Apex Class` on the upper left you can see the coverage of code. see my edited post

Comment: I have checked there only 10 lines are covered out of 22.I have edited my code and have added ** ** to lines that are not covered .

Comment: please check my edited code

Comment: The code coverage has gone to 27%. I have as it is copied your code ..

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Quote> quoList = new List<Quote>();
        for(Quote q : quoteList)
        {
            Quote quo = new Quote();
            quo.OpportunityId = Oppo.id;
            quo.name = q.name;
            quoList.add(quo);
            }
       // q.OpportunityId = Oppo.id;
        insert quoList;
        PageReference newPage = new PageReference('/'+Oppo.id);
        return newPage;
        }

        public PageReference QuotePage()
        {
        return Page.OppoQuotes;
        }
```

Comment: These lines are not covered in code